# "data parameter is nil" in iOS JSON Parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

i am newbie in iOS development. i do my JSON Parsing like as Then Error is `data parameter is nil`

First i Got Post id String From my Sql Table is Like as

```
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_myDatabase) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = @"SELECT * FROM ALLREADTABLE GROUP BY PostId";

    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_myDatabase, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        [self.postId removeAllObjects];
 while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            //NSString *personID = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            NSString *postId = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
self.postId addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", postId]];
}
```

Here i save PostId in to array and i pass Particular TableView Cell Post id to my WebView Controller When TableVIew Cell Was Selected

Code for that like as

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
post_id=[self.postId objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
WebViewController *webView=[[WebViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];
webView.postId=post_id;
}
```

And in my WebView i parse a JSON Data Like as

```
NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.janvajevu.com/webservice/specific_post.php?post_id=%@",self.postId];
NSLog(@"Url %@",url);
NSError *err;
NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
data2 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:nil error:&err];
NSDictionary *json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data2 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

Then Error is Occurred as `data parameter is nil` Please Give me Solution For that.

Comment: Is the URL correct? What is `err`?

Comment: @Wain my url is Correct I not Get data From Url. i think it is PostId Encoding Problem???? i mean i get post id from `sqltable` in `initWithUTF8String`.

Comment: So if the URL is correct then the question is what is the server not happy with. If there is an encoding issue then the URL isn't correct. What is the id / URL?

Comment: @Wain Server and Url both are Correct like as here my Url it is Working Fine.`http://www.janvajevu.com/webservice/specific_post.php?post_id=3331`

Comment: r u checkd ur table contains data or not

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik my Table Contain Data And When i Print Url then i get Url Like as `http://www.janvajevu.com/webservice/specific_post.php?post_id=3331`.

Comment: The error is `data parameter is nil` or `data2 parameter is nil`?  I don't see the variable data in your code. Are you sure that is the same variable?

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"%@", err);` show?

Comment: what u tried, initially u fetch the data from server and insert the data into local DB and finally u show the data into table, if its correct , where u not get the data/ problem faced...

Comment: @gabuh i define in imaplementation `NSData *data2;`

Comment: @Wain Error is like as `Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x10cdb260 {NSUnderlyingError=0x10c35a20 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}`

Comment: And the URL you put here is the actual log URL? What encoding is the data in the DB?

Comment: @Wain I Got PostId in Encoded Form like as `NSString *postId = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
self.postId addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", postId]];`

Comment: So from this I take that you don't know the format of the string, and that `self.postId` is actually an array (because that's what the code looks like). I also don't know if the URL you've shown is actually generated by your code. You need to answer all of the questions asked for enough information to be available to help.

Comment: @Wain Yes I not Know the Format Of the String. and Second Answer is `self.postid` is Array But I Get Postid From This `self.postid ` array like as `post_id=[self.postId objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];` and then post id to my WebView Controller also i posted in my code. and also when i log url then i got url like as `http://www.janvajevu.com/webservice/specific_post.php?post_id=3331`. but then Data Was Not Parsed.

Comment: Ok, is the column in the DB a string or an integer? (and is there a reason you aren't using Core Data?)

Comment: @Wain Specially Thank For Help i got An Answer Like as When i Got Post_id For selected cell then it is in UnKnown String Format but i encoded it like as ` post_id=[self.postId objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSString *encodedUrl = [post_id stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]; webView.postId=encodedUrl;` then i got it.